# org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException with different object Id

Tags: java, hibernate

I ran into a strange situation with the org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException error.

I could figure out which line of code cause the exception so I set a break point there to see which object was deleted. With my test data, the delete line only ran once, I compare the deleted object's Id with the Id from the exception and they are different. I tried to set another break point before hibernate flush the session and remove all reference tho the object in the error log but the exception still be thrown. The only way to make the code run without exception is commenting the delete line.

Any idea why hibernate give me the the different Id?

Comment: It is difficult to tell without any details. Please add related program and full stacktrace.